# Cannot read first column of csv file for data driven test. Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, data-driven-tests, vstest

I'm automatically generating (through SourceText class) a csv file to use in a data driven test (vstest), with UTF-8 encoding. The TestContext cannot find find the First column header, it always throws an exception,

> System.ArgumentException: Column 'IsProductCreated' does not belong to
>   table .

If I manually add a dummy column into the beginning of each row, the test works.

The TestContext setup:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "9C118DF7_AssignMaterialsToProductionOrderWhenNotReleased.csv", "9C118DF7_AssignMaterialsToProductionOrderWhenNotReleased#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), 
DeploymentItem("..\\..\\MaterialAndContainer\\MaterialManagementTest\\_TestData\\9C118DF7_AssignMaterialsToProductionOrderWhenNotReleased.csv")]
```

Usage example:

```
productionOrderScenario.IsProductCreated = (DataDrivenReader.ReadBool(TestContext.DataRow["IsProductCreated"]));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Encoding of my SourceText instance to Encoding.Default, explicitly. That made it work. It's deceiving in my opinion that the Encoding.Default is not, well, the Default... Having no encoding made me try the other encodings, UTF8 seemed the right one, but it was not.